# In R, find non-linear lines from two sets of points and then find the intersection of those points

Tags: r, intersection, non-linear-regression, game-theory

Using R, I want to estimate two curves using points from two vectors, and then find the x and y coordinates where those estimated curves intersect.

In a strategic setting with players "t" and "p", I am simulating best responses for both players in response to what the other would pick in a strategic setting (game theory). The problem is that I don't have functions or lines, I have two sets of points originating from simulation, with one set of points corresponding to the player's best response to given actions by the other player. The actual math was too difficult for me (or matlab) to solve, which is why I'm using this simulated visual approach. I want to estimate best response functions (i.e. create non-linear curves) using the points, and then take the two estimated curves and find where they intersect in order to identify nash equilibrium (where the best response curves intersect).

As an example, here are two such vectors I am working with:

```
t=c(10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.1,10.1,10.1,10.1,10.1,10.1,10.1,10.1,10.1,10.1,10.1,10.1,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0)

p=c(12.3,12.3,12.3,12.3,12.3,12.3,12.4,12.4,12.4,12.5,12.5,12.5,12.6,12.6,12.7,12.7,12.8,12.8,12.9,12.9,13.0,13.1,13.1,13.2,13.3,13.4,13.5,13.4,13.5,13.6,13.6,13.7,13.8,13.8,13.9,13.9,13.9,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0)
```

For the first line, the sample is made up of (t,a), and for the second line, the sample is made up of (a,p) where a is a third vector given by

```
a = seq(10, 14, by = 0.1)
```

For example, the first point for the sample corresponding to the first vector would be (10.0,10.0) and the second point would be (10.0,10.1). The first point for the sample corresponding to the second vector would be (10.0,12.3) and the second point would be (10.1,12.3).

What I originally tried to do is estimate the lines using polynomials produced by lm models, but those don't seem to always work:

```
plot(a,t, xlim=c(10,14), ylim=c(10,14), col="purple")
points(p,a, col="red")

fit4p <- lm(a~poly(p,3,raw=TRUE))
fit4t <- lm(t~poly(a,3,raw=TRUE))
lines(a, predict(fit4t, data.frame(x=a)), col="purple", xlim=c(10,14), ylim=c(10,14),type="l",xlab="p",ylab="t")
lines(p, predict(fit4p, data.frame(x=a)), col="green")

fit4pCurve <- function(x) coef(fit4p)[1] +x*coef(fit4p)[2]+x^2*coef(fit4p)[3]+x^3*coef(fit4p)[4] 
fit4tCurve <- function(x) coef(fit4t)[1] +x*coef(fit4t)[2]+x^2*coef(fit4t)[3]+x^3*coef(fit4t)[4]

a_opt1 = optimise(f=function(x) abs(fit4pCurve(x)-fit4tCurve(x)), c(10,14))$minimum
b_opt1 = as.numeric(fit4pCurve(a_opt1))
```

EDIT: 
After fixing the type, I get the correct answer, but it doesn't always work if the samples don't come back as cleanly.

So my question can be broken down a few ways. First, is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. I know what I'm doing isn't perfectly accurate by any means, but it seems like a decent approximation for my purposes. Second, if there isn't a better way, is there a way I could improve on the methodology I have listed above.

Comment: Your code is correct... I just edited it. Try restarting R, clearing all objects from your session, and copy/pasting the edited code. I think you were just overwriting objects. =)

Comment: I found the typo causing me issues... in that last line I have a_opt when it should have been a_opt1 and that was causing me problems. Glad to know the code actually works. If you have any suggestions to improve it I'm all ears though!

Comment: See my answer below.... you edited it again and changed the lowercase `p` variable back to an uppercase `P`. It's probably only working in your session because there's a left-over upper case `P`. If you're in RStudio, would recommend going into `Tools > Global Options` and unchecking `Restore .RData into workspace at startup` and setting `Save workspace to .RData on exit` to `Never`. Also uncheck options under `History` and `R Sessions`. This ensures you have a clean workspace each time you restart R and helps avoid these types of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart your R session, make sure all variables are cleared and copy/paste this code. I found a few mistakes in referenced variables. Also note that `R` is case sensitive. My suspicion is that you've been overwriting variables.

```
plot(a,t, xlim=c(10,14), ylim=c(10,14), col="purple")
points(p,a, col="red")

fit4p <- lm(a~poly(p,3,raw=TRUE))
fit4t <- lm(t~poly(a,3,raw=TRUE))
lines(a, predict(fit4t, data.frame(x=a)), col="purple", xlim=c(T,P), ylim=c(10,14),type="l",xlab="p",ylab="t")
lines(p, predict(fit4p, data.frame(x=a)), col="green")

fit4pCurve <- function(x) coef(fit4p)[1] +x*coef(fit4p)[2]+x^2*coef(fit4p)[3]+x^3*coef(fit4p)[4] 
fit4tCurve <- function(x) coef(fit4t)[1] +x*coef(fit4t)[2]+x^2*coef(fit4t)[3]+x^3*coef(fit4t)[4]

a_opt = optimise(f=function(x) abs(fit4pCurve(x)-fit4tCurve(x)), c(T,P))$minimum
b_opt = as.numeric(fit4pCurve(a_opt))
```

As you will see:

```
> a_opt
[1] 12.24213
> b_opt
[1] 10.03581
```